# Make an input add-on button as a file attachment button in angularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make an input add-on button as a file attachment button in angularJs. The html code shows the button "Add File" which when clicked must open a file browse window and behaves same as .

Code used to create input-addon :

```
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label informationCollect">Attachments</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><span>Add File</span></button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `<input name="myFile" type="file">` instead of your button?

Comment: Yes,I tried that but what it is doing is in the input field it is showing the "choose file"button the default button which comes when we use this <input type="file"/> , but I don't want that, I have the ADD FILE button inside the input field and I want to make that button's functionality like when we click that it must open the file browse window showing files of our local machine.

Comment: Yes,I tried that but what it is doing is in the input field it is showing the "choose file"button the default button which comes when we use this <input type="file"/> , but I don't want that, I have the ADD FILE button inside the input field and I want to make that button's functionality like when we click that it must open the file browse window showing files of our local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<label for="fileInput" class="btn btn-secondary">
  Add File
</label>
<input type="file" style="display: none"  id="fileInput" />
```